# How to define custom Rule in Shake: Development.Shake.Core is hidden

Tags: shake-build-system

I am trying to use Shake which look very promising but I hit a small wall. I am quite new to haskell so maybe I am missing something obvious but here is my problem:

I want to define a new kind of Rule in my shake program. This rule would compute a value from dependencies and let shake store it in its database. So if the dependencies are up to date, the shake db value is always valid.

```
data PrjList = PrjList FilePath deriving (Typeable,Show,Eq,Hashable,Binary,NFData)

instance Rule PrjList [(String,FilePath)] where
    validStored q a = True

-- Generate the dependency
getProjectList :: FilePath -> Action [(String,FilePath)]
getProjectList dir = apply1 $ PrjList dir

-- We want to traverse recursivly all subdir but stop once we find a BuildConfig file
defaultProjectList :: Rules ()
defaultProjectList = defaultRule $ \(PrjList dir) -> Just $ do
     -- blabla...
     return []
```

However, if I try to `import Development.Shake.Core` I have

```
Could not find module `Development.Shake.Core'
It is a member of the hidden package `shake-0.7'.
it is a hidden module in the package `shake-0.7'
it is a hidden module in the package `shake-0.8'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

And If I don't import it, I have

```
`validStored' is not a (visible) method of class `Rule'
```

So how can one define new rules?

Bonus question is: is my idea interesting or is there a better way to do it? When thinking about how to use shake, I had lots of rules which would have this behavior. This avoid having lots of temporary file and take advantage of the shake db. In fact my next step would be to try to define a generic rules for "filesystem free rules". User would just have to provide a `key → Maybe (Action value)` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shake-0.4 and above `validStored` was removed from the `Rule` class, and replaced with:

```
storedValue :: key -> IO (Maybe value)
```

So instead of defining whether the value is still correct or not, you return the stored value. That makes what you are trying to do a little harder, but still possible. You can define your `value` type as:

```
data MyValue a = RealResult a | Cheat
instance Eq a => Eq (MyValue a) where
    RealValue a == RealValue b = a == b
    _ == _ = True
```

Now you can define `storedValue _ = return $ Just Cheat`, and an existing value will always be considered valid.

The reason for making these "cache" rules harder was because I decided they aren't such a great idea, for three reasons:

1. If you get one of these rules wrong as you are writing the build system, you have to delete the Shake database to get back to a valid state.
2. You can't easily see what has been generated, so have to resort to tracing which is hard in a large multithreaded system.
3. At every run of your build system, even if there is nothing to do, Shake must deserialise the whole database including any large values you have stored in there.

I have found that if you just use temporary files, everything becomes more straightforward.

I can imagine there is some scope for caching the deserialisation of the contents of a file, e.g. if you are storing complex structures in a file, but I don't yet have a good API for doing that.

**In Shake 0.9 and above**

The function newCache provides a way to cache the deserialisation of the contents of a file.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast and comprehensive response!

Comment: (5min max for edit :S) I suppose I can just create tons of small files. I was thinking the trend was more toward putting things in a db to improve performance but now I see your point. Perhaps using a 'real' db like sqlite with edition tools and paging would solve the problems (even more if the value where serialised in human readable form).

Comment: Yes, if it was a real db there would probably be ways to view what was in it, which solves most of these issues. I wonder what the impact on performance would be (shake is quite optimised), but it would give some benefits.